# How to run a jQuery plugin once from a Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am sure what I am trying to achieve is easy, but having spent 2 days with `Angular` I'm still stuck.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('mays', []);

app.controller('Slider', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sliderItems = [
        {
            number: 1,
            title: 'Goals',
            text: 'We did stuff and stuff'
        }
    ];
});

//A directive is what I believe I need.


//JS Plugin

app.directive('sliderDirect', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             $('.slider').royalSlider();
        }
    };
});
```

I must admit, jQuery for me is overkill, but I'm lazy and want to start things quickly.

**HTML/Jade**

```
ul(class='slider royalSlider rsDefault', ng-repeat='item in sliderItems', ng-model='sliderDirect')
       li
           h1 {{item.title}}
               p {{item.text}}
               img(ng-src='/img/news/{{item.number}}.jpg')
```

Basically, all I need is the plugin to run once `Angular` has built up the `markup`.

Comment: realistically you should instead be doing `$(element).royalSlider()`. You've shown us what you have, but you didn't tell us what it is or isn't doing. What is wrong with it? What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: You're declaring the directive `sliderDirect`, but you're not using in the HTML you show?

Comment: I think op attempted to with `ng-model='sliderDirect'` (which of course is wrong)

Comment: op has no idea what he is doing :) I read through the documentation from angular, its good. But still, left me with no idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the directive as an attribute, not a model:

```
ul(class='slider royalSlider rsDefault', ng-repeat='item in sliderItems', slider-direct)
```

Angular will automatically convert camel case directives to the following `sliderDirect` -> `slider-direct` for use in the HTML. You should also be targeting the `element` variable in the `link` function if you want the directive to apply to the element with the attribute:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         $(element).royalSlider();
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed, I read about the auto conversions, interesting I completely didn't apply this logic!